# Nginx and php5-fpm constant 502 and 504 errors

Tags: server, mysql, php, nginx

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx (no Apache), php5-fpm, MySQL and Ajenti with Ajenti-V. I installed everything fine and managed to install some plugins and themes on my Wordpress, then just recently I've been getting a lot of 502 and 504 errors. The site loads up just rarely. Sometimes I restart Nginx and Php and it will load once and then die again.

This code is under my PHP-FastCGI:

```
try_files $uri =404; 
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
```

My server has 2 cores and 1GB RAM. this is the result of my free -m when the site is loading up.

```
root@empire:~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024        737        286         67          0        252
-/+ buffers/cache:        485        538
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Please tell me what info is needed to detect where's the error.

I am kinda new to this. Thanks!

Comment: 502 and 504 suggest that php5-fpm might be failing to respond, have you tried restarting the php5-fpm process?

Comment: Yes I have tried that but to no success. After restarting it the site will work for like 2 minutes tops.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the volume of traffic coming to your site compared to when your site goes down.  My *guess* would be you have code or something that ends up with a memory leak or consuming too much RAM or ends up eating system resources and hangs while it 'tries' to finish a previous call, which could make the gateway nonresponsive and timeout.  But without a lot more time and effort to track what's going on on the system when it dies off, that could be very very difficult to achieve.

Comment: Traffic would only be coming from me. I'm just on the phase of designing my website. How can I detect which processes are taking too much RAM? On my Ajenti php-fpm has an X mark which means there's got to be something wrong.